# Horizontal scroll nav bar with dropdowns content outside scroll

Tags: html, css

I need to design a nav bar menu with "n" dropdowns so I want to place a horizontal scroll to be able to scroll through each button, however with the code that I have at the moment it is working but the content of the dropdown remains inside the scrolly so no It's how I look for it.

Is like in [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_menu_hor_scroll) example but instead of links dropdown buttons,

Below I attach the code that I am using at the moment.

I would appreciate any help or suggestion.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>


.scrollmenu {

  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Dropdown Menu</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="scrollmenu">
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd get rid of the scrollbar and use a JS based carousel component instead. Or better, would reorganize the menu.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>


.scrollmenu {

  overflow: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Dropdown Menu</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="scrollmenu">
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

i think you are looking for this..try this i hope this works...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this solution its not what im lookinf for, i want to scroll only the part of the dropdown buttoms. Like in [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_menu_hor_scroll) expample but with dropdowns

Answer (score 1):

I added another wrapper element for positioning, now the content is displayed as expected, also when scrolling horizontally:

```css
.dropdown {
  // remove next line
  // position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Here you can directly test it:

```css
.scrollmenu {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Here you can directly test it:

```css
.scrollmenu {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: static;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.dropdown-content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<h2>Dropdown Menu</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="scrollmenu">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content-wrapper">
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content-wrapper">
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content-wrapper">
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content-wrapper">
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content-wrapper">
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content-wrapper">
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content-wrapper">
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content-wrapper">
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content-wrapper">
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content-wrapper">
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that there are elements below the nav bar so you can't specify that height because it would move the content below

Comment: Now I understand what you need. I've updated my answer, should work for you as expected.

Comment: Yes it is something like that, however, I don't know if you noticed that your solution has problems with the content of the dropdown menus when you're scrolling to the right

Answer (score 0):

try `overflow-x: auto;`:

```css
.scrollmenu {
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 600px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollmenu">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this solution it doesnt work

Comment: can you please tell me what exactly you issue is with this one so I can fix or create another solution, I'm here to help :)

Comment: The content of the dropdown (Link1,Link2,Link3) is inside the scroll not outside, so I have to scroll in order to see the dropdown content, I really don't see any difference with the code I attached

Comment: do you want to make the dropdown content sticky? or what

Comment: I want the button to be inside the scroll but the content of the button (link1, link2,link3) appears outside the scroll, currently it appears inside

Comment: I want the content of the dropdown to appear outside the scroll so that I don't have to scroll to see the content when I mouse over the button.

Comment: then you just need to add height to it, because the browser trying to fit the content in very small height and this causes the horizontal scroll, check the edit.